# Windows: Escape spaces in command

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute a simple command with path containing spaces

```
$solution = "test.sln"
$msbuild = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
Exec { iex "$msbuild `"$solution`" /t:clean"}
Exec { iex "$msbuild `"$solution`"" }
```

This throws an error

```
Exception: The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name
```

which seems to be because the `$msbuild` command isn't properly quoted. Tried quoting the command (and escaping quotes with backticks) but still no luck

```
$msbuild   = "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`""
```

How can you correctly escape/quote above? What are the escaping rules in Powershell?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "exec"; is it a custom function?  What does it do?

Comment: Yes, it's a custom function (I'm not sure what it does though). I _assume_ it executes the commands within the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

```
$msbuild = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}" + '\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
```

Try this way. No spaces, so path should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try using the the *Call* operator ([&](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347588.aspx)) instead of invoke-expression?  I'm not sure how any output will be processed though.

```
$solution = "test.sln"
$msbuild = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
Exec { & $msbuild $solution /t:clean}
Exec { & $msbuild $solution }
```